# Is there a way of using Python/Tkinter Canvas's highlightthickness using turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tk-toolkit

I am extremely new to Python and just started working in turtle contrary to tkinter.

I've been trying to make a borderless window using overridedirect(True) and making the  background color 
 of the window transparent by using `wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "color")` which I had to use "`turtle.Screen().getcanvas()._root()`" to be able to use the mentioned methods using turtle.

using the two methods indeed removes the window's border and turns the background of the window transparent although there seems to be a "frame" that so far I haven't found a way to remove nor did I manage to figure out(or find online) how to apply highlightthickness=0 to my code/in turtle.

I attached an image showing the undesired frame, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

-Omri
    [image: Undesired frame]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up making a Canvas, passed the Canvas into TurtleScreen and then passed TurtleScreen into RawTurtle.

Doing so allows me to draw analog clock hands using turtle on an analog clock image while still being able to make the window draggable,
with no border(without the undesired frame mentioned/linked above) and with a transparent background. [Current clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ARr4.jpg)